# Frage zur grammatikalischen Beziehung zweier Wortgruppen und deren Bedeutung

Tags: punctuation, comma

Gegeben sind folgende zwei Formulierungsvarianten derselben Aussage, welche der zurzeit vom *Rat für deutsche Rechtschreibung* forcierten [Grammatik](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2017.pdf) entsprechen.

> **1.** Es werden verschiedene das Design betreffende Entscheidungen
> diskutiert.
>
> **2.** Es werden verschiedene, das Design betreffende Entscheidungen
> diskutiert.

§71 dieser Grammtik besagt, dass "Gleichrangige (nebengeordnete) Teilsätze, Wortgruppen oder Wörter grenzt man mit Komma voneinander ab". Das bedeutet, dass nach $71 das Komma, welches in **2.** genutzt wird, *verschiedene* und *das Design betreffende* als nebengeordnet bezeichnet. In **1.** fehlt diese Bezeichnung.

Ich wüsste gerne, ob in Beispiel **1.** eine Hi­e­r­ar­chie zwischen *verschiedene* und *das Design betreffende* besteht, und wenn ja, welche Auswirkungen diese auf die Bedeutung der Aussage hat.

Ich intressiere mich auch für Nuancen, auch solche, die vielleicht in der jüngeren Zeit verschwunden sind (z.B. durch die Rechtschreibreform von 1996).

---

Ich hoffe, der grausige Titel kann verschmerzt werden, er ist schon das Ergebnis intensiver Überlegungen. Ich nehme an, ein Linguist wäre in der Lage, einen besseren zu finden…

Comment: Fehlt nicht ein Komma? 2. Es werden verschiedene, das Design betreffende, Entscheidungen diskutiert.

Comment: @Thomas, nein. Nach dem letzten Element einer Aufzählung kommt im Deutschen kein Komma.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Es ist wirklich die Frage, ob es eine Aufzählung oder ein Nachtrag ist. Meines Erachtens ist es eben keine Aufzählung, wie auch in meiner Antwort geschrieben. Man kann nämlich nicht schreiben: Es werden das Design betreffende, verschiedene Entscheidungen diskutiert.

Comment: @Thomas, in dem Posting geht es gar nicht um das Thema _Nachtrag_. Deine Frage bezüglich eines fehlenden Kommas, die du im Irrglauben gestellt hast, dass es dem Fragesteller um die Abgrenzung eines Nachtrag ginge, passt also gar nicht.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Naja, es geht schon darum, was es eigentlich ist (semantisch) und damit auch um die richtige Kommasetzung (syntaktisch).

Answer (score 2):

Mein erstsprachliches Gefühl sagt mir folgendes:

Technisch gesehen ist die Bedeutung der beiden Beispielsätze in der Tat leicht verschieden. Etwa so (mit mathematischen Klammern):

> 1. Es werden (verschiedene (das Design betreffende)) Entscheidungen diskutiert.
> 2. Es werden (verschiedene (das Design betreffende) Entscheidungen) diskutiert.

In 1. ist *(verschiedene (das Design betreffende))* gefühlt enger aufeinander bezogen. *Verschiedene* richtet sich direkt auf *das Design betreffende*.

In 2. sind *(verschiedene Entscheidungen)* in direkter Bindung, und *(das Design betreffende)* wird als - möglicherweise auch verzichtbare - Zusatzinformation hinzugefügt.

Jedoch komme ich auch bei längerem Überlegen nicht auf ein Szenario, wo dies einen mehr als theoretischen Unterschied machen würde.

Der Unterschied liegt wohl nicht im Szenario, das beschrieben wird, sondern darin, wie der Sprecher die Information strukturiert.

Aber vielleicht findet noch jemand ein Beispiel, wo diese beiden Arten, die Information zu strukturieren, auch unterschiedliche Realien beschreiben?

Answer (score 1):

Der §71 behandelt gleichrangige Nebensätze und Adjektive, was hier nicht der Fall ist. §78 ist hier zutreffend, das ist ein Zusatz oder Nachtrag, das benutzen von Kommata liegt im Ermessen des Autors.

Der Hauptunterschied liegt eher im gesprochenen Wort, durch das Komma wird die Bedeutung des Designs hervorgehoben. Beim Vorlesen des Satzes wird eine Pause eingefügt. Das Wort verschieden wird damit klarer erläutert. Allerdings ist der Unterschied m.E. in diesem Beispiel wirklich extrem klein.

Ausführliche Beispiele und Erläuterungen sind hier zu finden: [Link](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Interpunktion/Komma/Zusatz.html).

Answer (score 0):

Man nehme ein paar einfachere Beispielsätze:

> In dem Säckchen sind grüne, gelbe und rote Murmeln drin.

Das ist eindeutig eine Aufzählung, und es ist klar, dass es keine Murmeln gibt, die *gleichzeitig* grün, gelb und rot sind. zwischen die aufgezählten Eigenschaften gehört ein Komma.

> In dem Säckchen sind nur gelbe runde Murmeln drin.

Das ist eindeutig keine Aufzählung, es ist klar, dass alle Murmeln im Säckchen gelb **und** rund sind. Ein Komma wird nicht gesetzt.

Nehmen wir deinen Beispielsatz her

> Es werden verschiedene das Design betreffende Entscheidungen diskutiert

kann man annehmen, dass die Entscheidungen *alle* **gleichzeitig** das Design betreffen und verschieden sind. Es handelt sich wohl nicht um eine Aufzählung, es gehört kein Komma hin.

Answer (score 0):

Bei der Beurteilung dieser Frage scheint mir der grammatische Status - genauer gesagt der Wortart-Status - des Attributs *verschiedene* nicht auf der Hand zu liegen.

> Kurz gesagt kann es sich bei '**verschiedene**' in der genannten Nominalgruppe um ein
>   **Determinativ** bzw. einen Determinanten und bei *das Design betreffende* um ein normales partizipiales Attribut handeln. Dann wäre es m.E. falsch, das Determinativ wie ein
>   Adjektiv zu behandeln und ihn durch Komma wie ein Adjektiv in eine
>   Aufzählungsreihe einzustellen.

Als **Determinativ/Determinant** bezeichne ich Wörter innerhalb einer Nominalgruppe, deren Funktion das *Determinieren* und nicht wie beim Adjektiv das *Spezifizieren/Präzisieren* (ein *blaues* Auto) oder *Signalisieren einer Relation* (= Zuordnung zu einer Teilmenge, Klasse: *französischer Käse*) ist.

Quantifizierende Adjektive bzw. Artikelwörter/Pronomen nehmen eine Zwischenstellung ein. Hier gibt es etliche Abgrenzungsprobleme. Viele Lexeme in artikelähnlicher Funktion lassen sich nicht eindeutig der Wortart Adjektiv oder der Funktionsgruppe Determinativ zuordnen.

**Die Funktion des *Determinierens***

Innerhalb einer Nominalgruppe ist das Determinieren durch folgende Funktionen gekennzeichnet:

- Markierung der Identifikation ("*unser* Herr Müller")
- Markierung von Vorerwähntheit / Bekanntheit ("*jener* Herr Müller")
- Zeigefunktion ("*Der* Mann (*da*) war's.")
- Generalisierung ("*Ein* Deutscher würde so etwas nicht sagen.")
- anzahl-/mengenmäßige Bestimmung ("*Kein* Mensch ist unsterblich.")
- Erfragen der vorgenannten Merkmale ("*Welcher* Mitarbeiter war das?)
- plus weitere

Das Determinativ trägt in der Regel mehrere dieser Funktionsmerkmale.

**Syntaktische und morphologische Merkmale von *Deteminativen***

- Innerhalb einer Nominalgruppe bilden die Determinative den Kopf.
- Sie sind normalerweise nicht untereinander kombinierbar.
- Sie können insofern keine 'schwachen' Endungen tragen.
- Sie sind, anders als Adjektive, prinzipiell nicht steigerbar.
- Viele haben formgleiche oder weitgehend formähnliche pronominale 'Zwillinge'.

Mehrere der genannten Merkmale stehen jedoch in Frage.

Kein Abgrenzungsmerkmal ist ihr morphologisches Verhalten in der Nominalgruppe, also ihre Eigenschaft, Träger von Kasus-, Genus- und Numerusmarkierungen zu sein. Das können Adjektive ebenfalls übernehmen, wenn die Determinative invariabel (z.B. *etwas* in *mit etwas warme**r** Milch*) oder wie die Possessive im Nominativ Maskulinum und Neutrum und im Akkusativ Neutrum endungslos sind (*mein neu**es** Auto*) oder wenn kein Determinativ vorhanden ist (*Ausflug bei schönst**em** Wetter*).

**Das Abgrenzungsproblem *Artikel/Pronomen* oder *Adjektiv***

Im Deutschen gibt es mehrfach das Problem, dass Wörter, die in den Wörterbüchern als Adjektive eingestuft werden, funktional-semantisch den Determinativen zuzurechnen wären, sich aber syntaktisch wie Artikelwörter verhalten, indem ein nachfolgendes Adjektiv 'schwach' dekliniert wird. Wären sie tatsächlich eindeutig Adjektive, müssten sie parallel dekliniert werden. Hier schwankt jedoch der Gebrauch. Beispiel *folgend-*:

> Ich habe gestern folgend**e** interessant**e** Details erfahren: Parallelflexion, *folgende* = 'Adjektiv'
>   Ich habe gestern folgend**e** interessant**en** Details erfahren: Das nachfolgende Adjektiv wird 'schwach' dekliniert, *folgende* trägt zusammen mit dem Plural-s die Plural+Nominativ/Akkusativ-Markierung, wie es auch *diese* in _dies**e** interessant**en** Details _ tun würde.

**Zum Status von *verschieden***

Verschieden wird in den Wörterbüchern als Adjektiv geführt. Ursprünglich ist es das Partizip Perfekt der Verbs 'verscheiden', das heute im Allgemeinen nur noch als gehobenes Synonym für 'sterben' bekannt ist. Der attributive Gebrauch von *verschieden* in Nominalgruppen ist lexikalisiert. Er kommt in zwei Bedeutungen vor:

1. sich unterscheidend, voneinander verschieden: *Das sind (zwei) verschiedene Paar Schuhe* (= figurativ für 'diese Dinge sind nicht gleichzusetzen).
2. mehrere, einige, nicht nur ein: *Es wurden verschiedene Themen besprochen.*

In beiden Bedeutungen kann *verschieden* allein den Kopf der Nominalphrase bilden, es kann aber auch anderen Determinativen wie ein Adjektiv folgen: 1.(/2.) *Unsere verschiedenen Standpunkte waren nicht auf einen Nenner zu bringen.* 2. *Die verschiedenen auftretenden Probleme...*

Interessanterweise verhalten sich die mit *verschieden(2)* bedeutungsähnlichen Determinative *einig-* und *etlich-* in bestimmten Kontexten wie *folgend*, also nicht absolut festgelegt hinsichtlich der Deklination eines nachfolgenden Adjektivs: *Er hatte einiges/etliches neue(s) Material dabei.* Allerdings treten hier schwach deklinierte Adjektive wesentlich seltener auf. Noch seltener gibt es solche Fälle bei *verschieden-*, man findet sie eher in älterer Literatur, z.B. bei Goethe: "Er brachte verschiedenes Interessant**e** mit..." (Tagebucheintrag in der Propyläenausgabe Bd. 40 S. 193)

Ob es solche Fälle auch für *verschieden* in seiner ersten Bedeutung '*sich unterscheidend*' gibt, mag dahinstehen.

**Diskussion der Ausgangsfrage**

Wenn in der Ausgangsfrage *verschieden* in seiner 'blassen' Bedeutung als Determinativ und vergleichbar mit 'mehrere' aufzufassen ist, darf es nicht durch Komma separiert werden, denn Artikel und mit Artikeln funktionsgleiche Einheiten werden nie mit einem Komma von der Nominalgruppe abgeteilt, deren sinneinheitlichen Zusammenhalt erst sie als Determinative stiften. Sie rangieren nicht auf derselben Ebene wie Adjektive, sondern sind von ihnen funktional wesensverschieden und können nicht mit Adjektiven auf gleicher Stufe in eine Reihe treten. Vgl. für diese Begründung den nicht korrekten Satz **Es wurden mehrere, das Design betreffende Entscheidungen diskutiert.*

Wenn jedoch *verschieden* hier in seiner literalen, 'starken' Bedeutung "*sich unterscheidend*" gemeint ist, ist ein Komma zumindest möglich. Eine Entscheidungshilfe könnte sein, ob das zweite Attribut durch Aufzählungs- bzw. Präzisierungsmarkierungen wie *oder, nämlich, insbesondere ...* erweitert werden kann: *Es werden verschiedene, insbesondere das Design betreffende Entscheidungen diskutiert.*

[Mit dem zweiten Teil meines Resümees bin ich noch nicht glücklich, weil die beiden Bedeutungen von *verschieden* nicht klar zu greifen sind. Vorerst stelle ich das jetzt so ein, Literaturangaben werden noch ergänzt, und wegen *verschieden* muss ich nochmal in verschiedene Wörterbücher kucken.]